# gcsfuse cannot mount when building a docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I am trying to mount a storage bucker inside my container during `docker build`. I've read other threads, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588578/docker-build-failing-when-using-gcsfuse-to-mount-google-storage?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/273) and understood that this may be a privileged problem. It can be solved by adding the `--privileged` flag in the `docker run` process, but I would like to get the bucket mounted right off the building stage.

Attached to the container, checked that both `fuse` and `gcsfuse` are installed. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is set, no problem with accessing Google APIs. Here's the error I am getting.

```
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
.
.
.
ENV GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates \
    && echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list \
    && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcsfuse

# Config fuse
RUN chmod a+r /etc/fuse.conf
RUN perl -i -pe 's/#user_allow_other/user_allow_other/g' /etc/fuse.conf

# Alter permission
RUN chmod a+w mount-folder

RUN gcsfuse -o --implicit-dirs bucket mount-folder
```

Comment: You should move this case to ServerFault.

Answer (score 3):

For mounting a bucker using gcsfuse, you need to run docker with `--privileged` flag. Now the question is, "How to build a docker image without any error in such case"? 
Scenario:
When in Dockerfile you have the line:

```
RUN chmod +x launcher.sh
USER ubuntu
RUN mkdir db
RUN gcsfuse mybucket /home/username/mypath
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python3.6","manage.py","runmodwsgi"]
```

You see

```
Step 8/12 : USER ubuntu
 ---> Running in 0d880396010b
Removing intermediate container 0d880396010b
 ---> 390ed28965e1
Step 9/12 : RUN mkdir mypath
 ---> Running in b1f657562f24
Removing intermediate container b1f657562f24
 ---> 002ca425ac4c
Step 10/12 : RUN gcsfuse mybucket /home/username/mypath
 ---> Running in cae87fd47c1d
Using mount point: /home/username/mypath
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

The command '/bin/sh -c gcsfuse database_simrut /home/ubuntu/db' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Solution:
Remove the line

```
RUN gcsfuse mybucket /home/username/mypath
```

from the Dockerfile and create a launcher script instead which has following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcsfuse mybucket /home/username/mypath
python3.6 manage.py runmodwsgi
```

and your new docker should look like:

```
RUN chown $USER:$USER $HOME
RUN chmod +x launcher.sh
USER ubuntu
RUN mkdir db
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./launcher.sh"]
```

Output:

```
Step 8/11 : USER ubuntu
 ---> Running in 83c0e73295c2
Removing intermediate container 83c0e73295c2
 ---> fad81733c14d
Step 9/11 : RUN mkdir mypath
 ---> Running in 5d83416f035e
Removing intermediate container 5d83416f035e
 ---> 4575ba28dc44
Step 10/11 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in 081dc094c046
Removing intermediate container 081dc094c046
 ---> 546c8edd43c3
Step 11/11 : CMD ["./launcher.sh"]
 ---> Running in 6780900e1b2d
Removing intermediate container 6780900e1b2d
 ---> 9ef9fd5af68c
Successfully built 9ef9fd5af68c
```